# UITabBarController with a UIPopOverController with Multiple Views

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

I am working on a small app, according to the requirement the app should have a tabBarItem with 3 items. For this I have programmatically created the tabBarController in the AppDelegate.m file and added the 3 different viewControllers, instantiated them and everything is working good. I see the tabBarItems and all views are working. In one of the views lets say in SecondViewController I show a popOverController where I used a UITableView and populate it with items. When I click one of the items it should show another view lets say sendFeedback. Until there everything is working fine, but as soon as this sendFeedback is presented as the modal view, it occupies the whole app i.e it hides the tabBarItem.

I present the important pieces of code here for review:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController1.title = @"First";              

    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController2.title = @"Second";

    UITableViewController *tableView3 = [[tableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"tableViewController" bundle:nil];
    tableView3.title = @"Third";

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, tableView3 ,nil];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [viewController1 release];
    [viewController2 release];
    [tableView3 release];

    return YES;
}
```

In my popOverViewController.m file I am checking which row is selected in the table according to that I present the view

```
#pragma mark - TableView Delegate Methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{        

    sendFeedback *sendEmailViewController = [[sendFeedback alloc]initWithNibName:@"sendFeedback" bundle:nil];

    downLoad *downloadFilelViewController = [[downLoad alloc]initWithNibName:@"downLoad" bundle:nil];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        [self presentModalViewController:sendEmailViewController animated:YES];
   else
        [self presentModalViewController:downloadFilelViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Can anyone guide me how to overcome this with the multiple views. In case if anyone requires more information from my side I would be glad to provide.

NOTE: It is the same with the other view (downLoad) as well

EDIT: Here is how I am initializing my PopOverController in the AppDelegate.m file

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

{
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]){

        NSInteger index = [[self tabBarController] selectedIndex];

        CGRect buttonFrame = [[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] subviews] objectAtIndex:index+1] frame];

        PopOverViewController *popoverView = [PopOverViewController new];       

        popoverView.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250, 85);

        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverView];

        NSLog(@"X:%f Y:%f",buttonFrame.origin.x,buttonFrame.origin.y);        

        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:buttonFrame inView:self.tabBarController.tabBar permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];        
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal view controllers are used to "block" your application and fulfill a task before you can proceed. So modal view controllers are not what you want to use.

Instead wrap your controllers which have to be shown in the popover in a navigation controller. In the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method you can push the corresponding view controller to the navigation stack.

To slove your problem:
At the place where you create the popovercontroller initialize it with a new UINavigationController. And the navigation controller you have to initialize with a rootviewcontroller namely PopOverViewController.m.

```
PopOverController *popoverContentController = [[PopOverController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverContentController];
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContentController];
```

And in PopOverController.m

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sendEmailViewController animated:YES];
else
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:downloadFilelViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi, Dominik thanks for pointing out that. Are there any examples using this navigation stack available, as I said I just started ios stuff. So would be helpful with an example, in case if there are some.

Comment: I highly recommend you to read [apples viewcontroller programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). This is very fundamental to iOS development, so take your time to read it carefully - it's worth it.

Comment: Hi Dominik, thats kind of you to give small piece of code, but I am getting a SIGABRT error when I click on the TabBarItem which should show the PopOverControl. Can you recommend the necessary changes which would suit my code. Thanks

Comment: Where do you display the UIPopover?

Comment: I display the UIPopOver when the user touches the 2nd tabBarItem in the SecondViewController class. And this is the error which I am getting "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'The content view controller argument must be the root of its associated view controller hierarchy.'"

Comment: Okay I guess you got something wrong with your idea of UITabBarController. I think you should read apples guidelines first..

Comment: Just for your information I have followed this link when creating the tabBar App:  http://mobileoverlord.com/displaying-a-uipopovercontroller-from-a-uitabbaritem/. I found this from the same forum. So you think that may be the problem.